# Does energy resistance or protection count as neutralizing acid for effects like acid arrow?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, damage

The two spells are similar in nature, they help protect you from damage taken from an energy type.

[Acid Arrow](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/acid-arrow)

> An arrow of acid springs from your hand and speeds to its target. You must succeed on a ranged touch attack to hit your target. The arrow deals 2d4 points of acid damage with no splash damage. For every three caster levels you possess, the acid, unless neutralized, lasts for another round (to a maximum of 6 additional rounds at 18th level), dealing another 2d4 points of damage in each round.

[Resist Energy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/resist-energy)

> This abjuration grants a creature limited protection from damage of whichever one of five energy types you select: acid, cold, electricity, fire, or sonic. The subject gains resist energy 10 against the energy type chosen, meaning that each time the creature is subjected to such damage (whether from a natural or magical source), that damage is reduced by 10 points before being applied to the creature's hit points. The value of the energy resistance granted increases to 20 points at 7th level and to a maximum of 30 points at 11th level. The spell protects the recipient's equipment as well.

[Protection from Energy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/protection-from-energy)

> Protection from energy grants temporary immunity to the type of energy you specify when you cast it (acid, cold, electricity, fire, or sonic). When the spell absorbs 12 points per caster level of energy damage (to a maximum of 120 points at 10th level), it is discharged.

Since both spells would protect you from the energy damage of the acid arrow (assuming you cast the correct form), is the acid neutralized or does it still exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The energy resistance caused by those spells (all of them) does not stop the acid arrow spell from trying to deal damage every consequent round. Should the protection effects end or otherwise be discharged, the now unprotected target will still take the ongoing damage coming from the spell.

Comment: The acid arrow lasts for extra rounds with a high enough caster level, and its this lingering acid which I need answered. So the acid is not wasted in this case.

Comment: @Fering Ok, now I answered the right question.

Answer (score 1):

The [Nushadir](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/advancedGear.html#nushadir) (alchemical base) takes a minute to take effect, which isnt enough for most acid spells. Dispel magic would "neutralize" this lasting effect.

There is one known magical item that can "neutralize" a spell effect, the [Spellsink](http://archivesofnethys.com/MagicArmorDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Spellsink) special armor enhancement.

However, my guess is that it's simply a leftover text from another era.

EDIT

On the [Dungeonscape: An Essential Guide to Dungeon Adventuring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0786941189) book for 3.5, there was an item called **Acid Neutralizer**.

> Acid neutralizer reduces the strength of nonmagical acid, such as the type found in a variety of common dungeon traps.
>
> Description: Acid neutralizer is a slippery white substance similar in appearance to soap. It is made and sold in fist-sized lumps wrapped in brown waxed paper. When dropped in acid, the neutralizer foams and fizzes, turbulently churning the acid for 5 seconds. Neutralized acid takes on the appearance of weakly colored water, retaining only a slight tint and no odor whatsoever.
>
> Activation: To use a lump of acid neutralizer, just drop it into a vessel containing acid (a free action). Unwrapping the lump is not necessary, because any acid strong enough to warrant neutralization will eat through the paper wrapping easily. Neutralization requires a full round, and the acid will remain at full strength until the start of your next turn.
>
> If you are immersed in acid while carrying lumps of acid neutralizer, they immediately activate unless stored in a stronger container, such as a metal tin. Being splashed with acid might activate the neutralizer if you keep it exposed, rather than stored in a jar.
>
> Effect: If you drop one lump of acid neutralizer into a container holding up to 10 cubic feet of nonmagical acid, the acid is permanently weakened such that contact with the acid deals no damage. Complete immersion in neutralized acid deals only 5d6 points of damage per round (instead of the usual 10d6 points). Acid that has been neutralized in this manner no longer gives off toxic fumes. Larger volumes of acid require additional doses; two lumps are needed to neutralize a 20-cubic-foot vat of acid.
>
> Neutralizer is far less effective against magic acids, which regain their full acidity after 3d6 rounds.
>
> If you wear a lump of acid neutralizer in a necklace or carry it otherwise exposed on your body, the lump prevents continuing damage from acid attacks for 1 minute after initial exposure. It has no effect against the initial damage dealt by an acid attack.
>
> Construction: DC 20 Craft (alchemy) check, 17 gp.
>
> Weight: 1 lb. Price: 50 gp.

Interestingly, the book was also written by [Jason Bulmahn](http://paizo.com/people/JasonBulmahn), Pathfinder's Lead Designer.

Answer (score 0):

What is meant by "neutralised" is not specified, and therefore up to interpretation. My interpretation would be that neutralising the acid would be an action taken to neutralise it with a base (some kind of alchemical item).